# CSS pattern that matches when style is NOT present

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a library (PrimeFaces) that adds a style to a `<th>` when a column is sortable. But I want to apply my own style when a column is NOT sortable: i.e. when that style is NOT in the `<th>`

Is there a way to do a CSS selector for when a style is NOT present without making any other presumptions about what is/isn't in the list of the element's style classes?

That is, I need to do this strictly within CSS without modifying the HTML.

Comment: Is it a inline style property that gets added or a class?

Comment: Sorry... I used careless wording.  It is a class that gets added.

Comment: No problems. If it is a class and you want to do it with pure CSS then suslov's answer should help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not()` selector:

```css
table th:not(.sortable){  }
```

Comment: This worked.   And actually... I had tried to do something like this before I posted in StackOverflow, but I probably got the syntax wrong or something.  Thanks fo much for the help.

In hindsight, this may have been an "easy" question for me to solve for myself, but I think it's good for StackOverflow to have answers for easy questions.   I have to believe people need this quite often, but I couldn't find any prior articles.

Comment: @DaBlick: Glad to help you, don't forget to [mark as answered](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Jquery and css solution below

```
$('table th').not('.sortclass'); //jquery selector

table th:not(.sortclass) //pure css selector
```